# Check if Notify Alert is Displayed - Bluetooth Notify On Disconnect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview, core-bluetooth

My iPhone app connects to a BLE Peripheral using this line of code:

```
[manager connectPeripheral:per.peripheral options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] 
forKey:CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey]];
```

I enable the option to notify the user upon the peripheral disconnecting which will only happen when the app isn't being used (i.e. the iPhone is locked or the app is in the background)

When the peripheral disconnects, it calls a function in which I display an alert to the user telling them it disconnected:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error {    
    //Show alert to the user
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Peripheral disconnected. Try connecting again. Error: %@", error.localizedDescription];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Peripheral Disconnected"
                                                    message:str delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

The problem that I have is that when the iPhone is locked and the peripheral disconnects, both alerts pop up and it makes the user click "OK" on both alerts. How can I check to see if the "NotifyOnDisconnect" alert is being displayed to cancel showing the other alert?

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid using `CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey` altogether and in your `-centralManager:didDisconnectPeripheral:` implementation, check if the app is in the background and present a [`UILocalNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if it is in the background *or* your existing `UIAlertView` if the app is in the foreground. This way only one alert will be presented.